# How to make only some object data searchable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's say I have this object

```
"results" : [
      {
         "Item.ad_title" : "Test Phone",
         "System.id" : "29183546",
         "Transaction.price" : "700.00",
         "Owner.phone_number" : "22225987",
         "Publication" : {
            "publication_text" : "bla bla bla "
         },
         "Item.id" : "142",
         "Owner.email" : "email@email.com",
         "Item.tags" : [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "teg3"
         ]           
      },
]
```

And a text input with `ng-model="search"` and a `ng-repeat="product in products | filter: search"`.

That works, but everything in the object is searchable including the owners phone number and email.

So is there a way to tell Angular to search specific data like only the `Item.ad_title`, `publication.publication_text`, `Transaction.price` and `Item.tags`?

Edit: I want this to to work with one search input field

Comment: Did you try `filter:{Item.ad_title:search}`?

Comment: Yes and it works partially. Now for example when i enter the email, it displays a blank space as it has something and not showing it, instead it should show the no results message.

Comment: To be exact when i serach "Test" it shows the item. When i search "22225987" (that is the phone number) it returns the item but not showing it and leaving a blank space. When i search for "dfsdfsf" it shows the no results message

Answer (score 1):

In [angular documentantion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) you can find it

```
<label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
<label>Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"></label><br>
<label>Equality <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"></label><br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

ng-mode="search.property" and then in the filter specify strict

Comment: Yes that works, thank you. But i would like to search more than one property. Not all and more than one. With one input field.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite properly given in the https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter docs:

Like:

```
ng-repeat="product in products | filter: {'Transaction.price': search}"
```